# My car will try to turn over but not fully engaged

Tags: starting, nissan, maxima

I have a 2000 Nissan Maxima with 196,000 miles. Just replaced starter, alternator, fuel pump and spark plugs. When I turn the ignition, the engine turns over once or twice, then stops.

This is what it sounds like:

https://youtu.be/Ldu8pedoGU0

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you say, " ... it won't fully crank" what do you mean? It just doesn't start? To most of us here, to not crank means it does nothing. Are there any codes?

Comment: @Victoria I edited your post to describe what I saw in your video.  Feel free to [edit](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/posts/58096/edit) the post again if that doesn't accurately describe your problem.

Comment: Did you check the battery?  Maybe try hooking up some jumper cables to another car and seeing if that helps at all.  Also, how long has it been since your Maxima started last?

Comment: Make sure the battery is good. Remove the belt and try again. It doesn’t sound like the engine is spinning fast enough. Whats the cranking rpm?